# Is Festering March cast repeatedly via the suspend ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The card text of [Festering March](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFestering%20March%5d) is as follows:

> Creatures your opponents control get -1/-1 until end of turn. Exile Festering March with three time counters on it.

It appears that you can cast this card repeatedly as you suspend it as part of its resolution.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's right. Otherwise, it would just be an overcosted [Make Obsolete](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMake%20Obsolete%5d). Even though the phrase is "*Exile* Festering March with three time counters on it." and not "*Suspend* Festering March with three time counters on it.", the card is still suspended according to the [Comprehensive Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020181005.txt),

> 702.61b A card is “suspended” if it’s in the exile zone, has suspend, and has a time counter on it.

and removing time counters and casting the spell without its mana cost works just like if you had suspended it from your hand:

> 702.61a Suspend is a keyword that represents three abilities. The first is a static ability that functions while the card with suspend is in a player’s hand. The second and third are triggered abilities that function in the exile zone. “Suspend N—[cost]” means “If you could begin to cast this card by putting it onto the stack from your hand, you may pay [cost] and exile it with N time counters on it. This action doesn’t use the stack,” and “At the beginning of your upkeep, if this card is suspended, remove a time counter from it,” and “When the last time counter is removed from this card, if it’s exiled, play it without paying its mana cost if able. If you can’t, it remains exiled. If you cast a creature spell this way, it gains haste until you lose control of the spell or the permanent it becomes.”

Comment: Note that there is no card that says anything like "suspend [cardname]"; it's always "exile with x time counters". Your answer makes it sound like the former would be the expected wording.

Comment: Festering March is part of a [cycle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[%22with%20three%20time%20counters%20on%20it%22]+[%22.%20exile%22]) of suspend cards which all would resuspend themselves with three time counters every time they resolve.  [Chronomantic Escape](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=126204) in particular was rather popular, because three of them make you forever immune from being attacked (unless the opponent had a counterspell)

Comment: @Hackworth right, it doesn't; still, I think this where the OP's confusion is coming from.